# KeyError: 'connection'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyowm

```
import pyowm

owm = pyowm.OWM ('198f60823e0dc5f4907dddbf73f75fb9', {'language' : 'ru'})

place = input('В каком городе/стране?')

observation = owm.weather_manager().weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.get_weather()

print(w)
```

D:\Python>python pogoda.py
В каком городе/стране?Лида

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pogoda.py", line 7, in <module>
    observation = owm.weather_manager().weather_at_place(place)
  File "C:\Users\Павел\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyowm\weatherapi25\weather_manager.py", line 53, in weather_at_place
    _, json_data = self.http_client.get_json(OBSERVATION_URI, params=params)
  File "C:\Users\Павел\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyowm\commons\http_client.py", line 123, in get_json
    builder = HttpRequestBuilder(self.root_uri, self.api_key, self.config, has_subdomains=self.admits_subdomains)\
  File "C:\Users\Павел\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyowm\commons\http_client.py", line 34, in __init__
    self._set_schema()
  File "C:\Users\Павел\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyowm\commons\http_client.py", line 39, in _set_schema
    use_ssl = self.config['connection']['use_ssl']
KeyError: 'connection'
```

Answer (score 1):

В OWM вы передаёте конфиг с одним ключом, игнорируя другие ключи, из-за этого у вас ошибка.

Советую вам сделать вот так:

```py
import pyowm
owm = pyowm.OWM('198f60823e0dc5f4907dddbf73f75fb9')   # Создать с конфигом по умолчанию.
owm.config["language"] = "ru"  # Поменять ключ language в конфиге на "ru"
```

В таком случае вы измените только ключ "language", не меняя другие ключи, установленные по умолчанию в конфиге.

Также, у вас есть ещё одна ошибка в коде.
В observation нет метода get_weather, в нём есть только атрибут weather.
Следовательно, вам необходимо обращаться к атрибуту weather, а не к несуществующему методу get_weather.

Суммируя всё выше написанное, вот рабочий код:

```py
import pyowm
owm = pyowm.OWM('198f60823e0dc5f4907dddbf73f75fb9')   # Создать с конфигом по умолчанию.
owm.config["language"] = "ru"  # Поменять ключ language в конфиге на "ru"

place = input('В каком городе/стране?')

observation = owm.weather_manager().weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.weather

print(w)
```

Я также вам советую сделать новый API ключ, и больше не отправлять свои ключи в интернет.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь)